# swagger.json link not showing up in swagger page

Tags: .net, swagger, swashbuckle

With my setup, I don't have a link on my swagger page to retrieve the swagger.json file. The swagger page appears, and I can see my API and make calls to it through the swagger page, but I have no swagger.json file link. In the image at the bottom has a link (not my page, someone else's). How can I change my setup to get this link to appear? The server is started by the line `WebApp.Start<WebApi>(url);` and below is my setup a

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {

        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*"));
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.EnableSwagger(c =>
        {
            c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "stuff");
        })
            .EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
            {
                c.DocumentTitle("Swagger UI");
            });
        

        app.UseWebApi(config);

        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
    }
```

[image]

Also screenshot of my UI (notice no link to swagger.json):

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of _your_ Swagger UI? Swashbuckle for WebAPI might be using an old version that has a different design.

Comment: Added, is there a newer version I can use for .net framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swashbuckle for WebAPI uses an older Swagger UI version (2.x) which displays the API definition URL in the header - in your example it's `http://localhost:34330/swagger/docs/v1`.

[image: Swagger UI 2.x displays the API definition URL in the input box in the green header]